# How to install custom bootstrap build via composer?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, composer-php

I have a **PHP** project I need to dive in. It uses the **Composer**. 
I need to add **bootstrap** to this project, and it has to be **configured** (include some components and exclude anothers). I also have **config.json** file for bootstrap build I need.

I successfully install bootstrap using composer command like so:

```
php composer.phar require twbs/bootstrap
```

But it gives me default build with completed set of bootstrap parts.

Can I use my **config.json** file to configure bootstrap installation with composer somehow? Or maybe I need to recompile installed bootstrap somehow?

Many thanks.